# my dashboard.php doesn't load even though the login details is correct

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can someone help me put this code in order? it keeps on loading the login.html page even though the login is correct. 
I actually wanted to create a user dashboard that has user details displayed on the dashboard.php so I used the page for authenticating users and also showing users details

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['search']))

{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'userregistration');
    $query = "select * from usertable where `email` ='" . $email . "' AND `password`='" . $password . "' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            $name = $row['name'];
            $balance = $row['balance'];
            $acc_level = $row['acc_level'];
            $invested = $row['invested'];
            $Btc_balance = $row['Btc_balance'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:../login.html');

        else
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: Storing passwords in plain text I see

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!x** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: I tagged it with mysqli, because most likely you are getting an error and discarding it immediately on reload. However, this question needs some debugging details and most importantly complete rewrite of this code. Please do not use this code ever.